# Kaa REST log appender issue

Tags: kaa

I have configured REST appender on DataCollectionDemo on the Sandbox. I have configured host = localhost, "/" at the end and beginning of URI path, no ssl. I have a http listener running on my localmachine. I have also disabled firewall on my machine. Now I cant receive the POST method on my server. Please help.

Comment: See if this is the same issue as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631121/rest-logappender-giving-500-and-then-400-error-while-posting-data-on-aws-beansta/42179579#42179579)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Thank you Anil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key errors faced and their solutions while deploying Kaa REST log appender:

Error 500: I found two errors with my configuration of RestLogAppender in the admin panel. First, I had put http:// before my host. Had to remove the same. Second, I should have mentioned Relative URI path starting and ending with a forward slash /.

Error 400: I had given slightly different names to the JSON fields in the Django models. The sequence of the fields did not matter but the name of fields did matter.

Comment: @sr33kanth If this answer worked for you, can u pls accept this as an answer?