# How to send data from rest api to a kaa server

Tags: kaa

How to send data from rest api to kaa server without using the sdk

the above it is possible or i only can push new data using the sdk  ?

I tried use the api methods but i don't know what is the appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you would be able to use anything other than example SDK to send data to Kaa. Kaa SDKs have implicit info about the schemas used in the kaa server. You can use a sample SDK and modify for your own use.

REST log appender provided with kaa is very easy to use. If you face any problem then you can search for other questions related to kaa REST log appender and you would be able to find a solution. If not, pls ask for help on your specific error msg or issue. You can also refer to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41631121/7269314)